# Import .ply files to unity 3D

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine, blender, 3dsmax

I am trying to import [.ply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_%28file_format%29) in to Unity 3D with vertex colors any way to accomplish this? I don't know how to convert .ply file to .obj, .dae or .fbx. As an example there should be a way to do .ply = .obj + .mtl 
Please help me

Comment: you can import the .ply in Blender or MeshLab(free/opensource) and export an obj

Comment: There are also some nice [ply libraries](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~ares.lagae/libply/) that support obj conversion. (External to Unity)

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin on the asset store that does that: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/15428

Comment: This importer is not longer availible